# How to compute statistical expectation of sgn(x-y)x?

Tags: statistics

Given two real random variables $x$ and $y$ following the zero mean Gaussian distribution, How can we compute $\operatorname{E}\{\operatorname{sgn}(x-y)x\}$?

- $\operatorname{E}\{\}$: statistical expectation
- $\operatorname{sgn}(x)$: sign function
- $x$ and $y$ are correlated.

If you know how to calculate it, please can you teach me about it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.